# iPhone - Referencing the application delegate within a generic class

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, reference, selector, uiapplicationdelegate

I a writing a generic class that may be used in different projects by link.
At some moment, I call a method on a listener given by the one that owns the object and kept by assign into the class.
But sometimes, that caller may disapear, so I want in that case to route the return message to the application delegate.

Here is how I do for the caller (the caller is the one that created and owns the instance of my class) :

```
if ([self.responseListener respondsToSelector:@selector(serverAnswered:error:)]) {
        // some job to construct the return object

        [self.responseListener performSelector:@selector(serverAnswered:error:) withObject:response withObject:nil];
    }
```

How may I reference the app delegate class in place of responseListener when the caller has disapeared ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with "caller" in "when the caller has disappeared". Here's how you can access the application delegate from anywhere, though.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

If you need to call methods on it unique to your particular application's delegate, you need to import it and cast.

```
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

// ...

MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

**Update:**

To call your own library methods on any app delegate, use a protocol.

```
// The app delegate in your library users app
#import "YourFancyLibrary.h"

@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, YourFancyLibraryDelegate>

// In YourFancyLibrary.h, declare that protocol
@protocol YourFancyLibraryDelegate
- (void)myFancyMethod;
@end

// Refer to it in the guts of your library.
id<YourFancyLibraryDelegate> delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
if (![delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(YourFancyLibraryDelegate)]) return;
if (![delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myFancyMethod)]) return;
[delegate myFancyMethod];
```

This will make your API clear as you specify what methods your library users need to implement, and is a good solution as it allows for compile time checks instead of relying on run time dynamic message sending.

You can also skip the protocol, and call methods on it directly.

```
id appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
SEL methodToCall = @selector(someMethod);
if ([appDelegate respondsToSelector:methodToCall]) {
    [appDelegate performSelector:methodToCall];
}
```

Comment: Yes, I want to call a custom method on the app delegate. As my class is generic and can be included in different projects, the class doesn't know the name of the Application delegate class tha is used into the project it is included in. Is there a way to write your second call without knwoing the class name of the app delegate.

Comment: The right thing to do is to require users of your library to implement a protocol in their app delegate. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I agree, but I cannot force the application to implement a method that will be called only for some specific cases, that occurs when a specific call is triggered onto the generic object. For all the other methods implemented in the generic class, that is useless. So I'd prefer to check if the app delegate has implemented that method, and if not, go to a third route.

Comment: You can make the protocol method optional and check if the app delegate responds to it. Will update my answer again.

Comment: And if the user forgets to write  `@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, YourFancyLibraryDelegate>`, nothing happens at compile time and the crash is sure.

Comment: So just use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate performSelector:....]` then? Also, you can use `conformsToProtocol` to check if the app delegate does, well, conform to the protocol. Updated answer again.

Comment: Ar the protocol lines needed ? As I can see, the check on respondsToSelectoçr should be enough, isn't it ?

Comment: @Oliver let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1980/discussion-between-august-lilleaas-and-oliver)

Comment: OK, so I guess that `[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate performSelector:....]` would be enough, like I do for any listener, with a check for respondsToSelector before ? That will call the method on my custom delegate ?